# How to display only introtext?

Tags: posts

For development of my custom template, I need to show only a intro text of some posts.

Can you help me how to achieve that?

More informations:

As we all know, single WP post is defined as:

```
This is post's introducion text
<!--more-->
Main post content, blah blah blah
```

All I need is somehow to display

> This is post's introducion text

... on frontend.

Comment: Please clarify what it is that you want, what you have tried so far, where you are stuck etc. Currently, it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add more details to it. If possible add examples

Comment: You mean you want excerpts on archive pages linking to the full posts?

Comment: yes. but with using the_excerpt() i'm getting whole post content

Comment: review http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Overriding_Archive.2FSingle_Page_Behavior

Comment: The question can be reworked. Not closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am sure that the logic of what I am about to post is too simple, I think it should get you started.

Your terminology is odd but what it seems you want is to display the "post before the more" part of the post body. To do that, you need to break the post content into "post before the more" and "post after the more". [There is a function for that.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_extended)

```
$pieces = get_extended($post->post_content);
// var_dump($pieces); // debug
echo apply_filters('the_content',$pieces['main']);
```

Inside a Loop, that should work just fine. In other contexts you may need something other than `$post->post_content`.

Excerpts, manually or automatically created, will not come into play so you may need to include that in the logic.

Comment: tnx! i made it also with <?php global $more;$more = 0;the_content("Read more..."); ?>, but i like your solution too